# How to make an array of diagonal matrices in R?

Tags: arrays, r, matrix, diagonal

I know how I can make an array of  N numbers of p*p matrices:

```
m=array(x, c(p,p,N))
```

which `x` could be a vector or a scalar. I want to make an array of diagonal matrices. Each matrix should be diagonal. I tried several ways but they don't work. Does anyone know about it?

Comment: Please share what you tried and what "don't work" means.

Comment: Use `matrix` and make the number of rows and columns equal. See https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/matrix.html

Comment: `replicate(2, diag(3))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't mind using a package, you could use `abind`:

```
library(abind)
do.call(abind, c(rep(list(diag(3)), 2), along = 3))
#, , 1
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    1
#
#, , 2
#
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: Nice library, did no know it!

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel It's not as efficient as your answer, but one doesn't need to hurt one's brain thinking too hard.

Answer (score 4):

It's a little bit clumsy but you can do this:

```
n = 3
num_of_matrix = 2

array(rep(c(diag(n)),num_of_matrix),c(n,n,num_of_matrix))
#, , 1

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    1

#, , 2

#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    1
```

Comment: Using R's implicit recycling when filling out arrays, it's cleaner to just do `array(diag(n), c(n,n,num_of_matrix))`

Comment: True! I prefered to mention all to be clearer but my way to cut was `array(c(diag(n)),c(n,n,num_of_matrix))`, your's far better :) !